# Limit of usage ui:inputDate in Lightning Application/Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to insert a great number  of ui:inputDate tags in one component and realized, that getting the following unknown error:

**Something has gone wrong. [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Aura.loadComponent(): Failed to initialize application. Event fired . Please try again.**

There is no any  documentation about limitation of usage  tags in components...
So the question is, does anyone know  how to workaround it and what is the limit?

**Update** 
with Winter '17  release bug  is  still here, but  another error message:

**Something has gone wrong. Error in defaultHandler for event: markup://aura:systemError [$A.auraError is not a constructor]**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after a lot of testing I have found that for now in Summer '16 release there is a straight  limitation of used `ui:inputDate` tag. The number of limit is **28**. With adding 29-th element, you will see this  unknown error.

**update**

sf support recognized it as bug. It is going to be fixed in Spring '17 release